# Download documentation for Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

I tried finding a way to download documentation of titanium appcelerator for offline reading

I searched a lot but couldn't find any direct or indirect way to download it

Has anyone downloaded documentation ?

Comment: I found this annoying too.  From the API documentation site, I haven't found a way to print it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a shell script out of user1537325's answer.  This is specific to Ubuntu 12.04, but you can probably modify it to your own OS without too much trouble.  Be sure to upvote his answer as well.

https://gist.github.com/eric-hu/4952258

**Warning:** The layout and color scheme of the generated docs look different from those of the online docs for Titanium 3.0.  I'm not sure if there are differences yet.  The output from jsduck also included many warnings about "Unknown type".

Comment: Thanks for the code . Problem is that currently I am on windows machine . I Will check this code when I get access to ubuntu

Comment: Ah, I was just providing this answer for the general community.  I uploaded the generated html [here](https://github.com/eric-hu/ti_docs).  Hopefully you have git on Windows :P

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible (as far as I know) to make the docs offline directly using the online version.

However it is possible to build the docs using the source code, as we all know that Titanium is open-source.

1. Download the source from: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile, or clone the repo with: `git clone https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile.git`
2. Unzip the source code
3. `cd titanium_mobile-master`
4. Ensure that you have python installed, as well as `pyyml` and `pygments`, you can install them with: `sudo easy_install pyyml, pygments`
5. Ensure you have jsduck installed in your system, if not then install it with: `gem install jsduck`
6. write this command: `apidoc/docgen.py --format=jsduck --output=dist/apidoc`
7. `cd dist/apidoc`
8. `jsduck --touch-examples-ui --output Whole titanium.js`, where `Whole` is the output directory containing the generated docs

If you want the builtins to be included in your generated docs make the last command:
`jsduck --builtin-classes --touch-examples-ui --output Whole titanium.js`

That is it, you have a full searchable Ti docs offline.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://github.com/appcelerator/doctools, which contains the jsduck tag definitions and some scripts to build the docs.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, I have found a working solution for one of the most common problems Ti developers face.

**Working offline with Titanium Studio:**

After going offline, Titanium Studio won't allow you to neither create new projects nor build/package existing projects, to work this around:

-- I have applied this procedure prior to inventing the one below, so I am not sure if it has any effect: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119830/use-titanium-withour-internet-connection-or-logged-off, Adam Fisher's procedure.

1. Open Titanium Studio while offline.
2. go to: `~/.titanium`
3. `vim auth_session.json`
4. change the `false` to `true`.
5. Done

Now you can build and create new project as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly download the API documentations from the appcelerator site, but you can use *offline surfing softwares* to download the website for offline reading

Here are some links from where you'll get some notes

1. [Training resources from appcelerator](http://training.appcelerator.com/training-resources)
2. You can download and read [Appcelerator Titanium Smartphone App Development Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513961) which will help you for developing applications with titanium
3. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/BNAPP_ebook
4. Also you can refer this answers [Learning titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814707/learning-titanium-for-android/12832343#12832343)

Comment: Thanks. Ebook seems to be quite helpful at present

Comment: now a days titanium is very familiar and hence more helps and documentations are available. You can easily use them from the above links

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for the Mac called Dash (http://kapeli.com/dash).  Dash is an off-line documentation browser for software developers.  It supports many languages, one of which is the Titanium API; it's a must...if you use a Mac.

However, all the documentation for the Titanium API is available as JSON files (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/data/index.html), so I guess it's just a matter of building an off-line JSON reader.

R

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .mobi file from 
"http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/BNAPP_ebook"
and use a mobi to pdf to converter to convert it to pdf format. You can use the free service provided at :
http://www.mobi-to-pdf.com/
to do the conversion.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac OS X you can install Dash

[Dash link](https://kapeli.com/dash)

[Dash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBSKK.png)